# Extract a byte into a specific bit

Tags: c#, uwp

I have one byte of data and from there I have to extract it in the following manner.

`data[0]` has to extract

```
id(5 bit)
Sequence(2 bit)
HashAppData(1 bit)
```

`data[1]` has to extract

```
id(6 bit)
offset(2 bit)
```

Required functions are below where byte array length is 2 and I have to extract to the above manner.

```
public static int ParseData(byte[] data)
{
       // All code goes here
}
```

Couldn't find any suitable solution to how do I make it. Can you please extract it?

**EDIT**: Fragment datatype should be in `Integer`

Comment: Please add the `FragmentData` type to the question, it's unclear what types you're wanting the extracted data to be.

Comment: Data type should be integer

Comment: if it should be an int why declared public static FragmentData ParseData(byte[] data) instead public static int ParseData(byte[] data), makes no sense

Comment: @J.Salas I have another class named of FragmentData that's why I put it here. Ok, for its simplicity I will edit it into Integer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
    int id = (data[0] >> 3) & 31;
    int sequence = (data[0] >> 1) & 3;
    int hashAppData = data[0] & 1;
    
    int id2 = (data[1] >> 2) & 63;
    int offset = data[1] & 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it for the first byte:

```
byte value = 155;
byte maskForHighest5 = 128+64+32+16+8;
byte maskForNext2 = 4+2;
byte maskForLast = 1;
byte result1 = (byte)((value & maskForHighest5) >> 3); // shift right 3 bits
byte result2 = (byte)((value & maskForNext2) >> 1); // shift right 1 bit
byte result3 = (byte)(value & maskForLast);
```

Working demo (.NET Fiddle):
**https://dotnetfiddle.net/lNZ9TR**

Code for the 2nd byte will be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you're uncomfortable with [bit manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators), use an extension method to keep the intent of `ParseData` clear. This extension can be adapted for other [integers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) by replacing both uses of `byte` with the necessary type.

```cs
public static int GetBitValue(this byte b, int offset, int length)
{
    const int ByteWidth = sizeof(byte) * 8;

    // System.Diagnostics validation - Excluded in release builds
    Debug.Assert(offset >= 0);
    Debug.Assert(offset < ByteWidth);
    Debug.Assert(length > 0);
    Debug.Assert(length <= ByteWidth);
    Debug.Assert(offset + length <= ByteWidth);

    var shift = ByteWidth - offset - length;
    var mask = (1 << length) - 1;
    return (b >> shift) & mask;
}
```

Usage in this case:

```cs
public static int ParseData(byte[] data)
{
    { // data[0]
        var id = data[0].GetBitValue(0, 5);
        var sequence = data[0].GetBitValue(5, 2);
        var hashAppData = data[0].GetBitValue(7, 1);
    }

    { // data[1]
        var id = data[1].GetBitValue(0, 6);
        var offset = data[1].GetBitValue(6, 2);
    }

    // ... return necessary data
}
```