# Convert multiple types data into a specific length of byte array

Tags: c#, uwp, bit-manipulation

Following this question I have [extracted a byte into a specific bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518753/extract-a-byte-into-a-specific-bit). Now I have to go back to origin. But couldn't find any suitable solution to back. I have a byte array and it's length is 3.
Extracted the array in the following function.

```
public static void ParserData(byte[] data)
{
    
    int x = data[0] >> 6;
    int y = data[0] & 63;
    byte[] btMac = data.SubArray(1, 2);
    string btmac= BitConverter.ToString(value: btMac, 0);
    
}
```

From the above `ParserData` function I have extracted **x** and **y** from  `data[0]` and `btmac` from `data.SubArray(1, 2)`. Now I have to push **x** and **y** value to `data[0]` and `btmac` to `data[1,2]` in `GenerateData(int x, int y, string btmac)` function so that the both function will be vice-versa.

```
public static byte[] GenerateData(int x, int y, string btmac)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[3];
    
    // code goes here

    return data;
}
```

Getting stack to solve this issue and find no solution. How do I do that?

Comment: There isn't a built in method for the inverse of `BitConverter.ToString`, so you will have to write one yourself. Shouldn't be too hard though.

Comment: @Sweeper My question is not out of there to inverse `BitConverter.ToString`. What's the logic to put `x` and `y` into `data[0]`. If you convert any integer into bytes it returns 4 bytes but I want this integer into a single byte if you notice my code you will get the point. My expected result byte array will be confined to 3 bytes

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this

```
var xy = (byte)((x << 6) | y) // combine bits from x and y into a byte, this assumes values are in a valid range
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using( var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms)){
    bw.Write(xy); // write the xy byte
    bw.Write(btmac[0]); // write the single character in the string
}
var result = ms.ToArray(); // create an array with the result
```

Note that this is completely untested.

In general I would recommend using a real serialization library rather than messing around with serializing/deserializing binary data yourself. Something like Protobuf.Net should only produce marginally larger data-size, while being **much** easier to use, and also provide much more compatibility in just about every way.